# ONVIF: Listing all hostname of IP cameras in same network

Tags: rtsp, hostname, onvif

```
DiscoveryManager manager = new DiscoveryManager();
manager.setDiscoveryTimeout(10000);
manager.discover(new DiscoveryListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDiscoveryStarted() {
        System.out.println("Discovery started");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDevicesFound(List<Device> devices) {
        for (Device device : devices)
            System.out.println("Devices found: " + device.getHostName());
    }
});
```

I am using above code for get all host names of IP cameras, One thing I wish to mention before describe my problem. I am using IP webcam android app to make my mobile act like IP cam. With this setup above code give all host names. But this snippet didn't give the actual IP camera's hostname. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello guys here is the solution for this question.

```
public class OnvifMediaURL {

    OnvifManager manager = new OnvifManager();

    public void mediaURlFinder(String string) {

        OnvifDevice device = new OnvifDevice(string);
        manager.getServices(device, new OnvifServicesListener() {

            @Override
            public void onServicesReceived(@NotNull OnvifDevice onvifDevice, OnvifServices paths) {
            }
        });

        manager.getDeviceInformation(device, new OnvifDeviceInformationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDeviceInformationReceived(@NotNull OnvifDevice device,
                    @NotNull OnvifDeviceInformation deviceInformation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        manager.getMediaProfiles(device, new OnvifMediaProfilesListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMediaProfilesReceived(@NotNull OnvifDevice device,
                    @NotNull List<OnvifMediaProfile> mediaProfiles) {
                manager.getMediaStreams(device, mediaProfiles.get(0), new OnvifMediaStreamURIListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onMediaStreamURIReceived(@NotNull OnvifDevice device,
                            @NotNull OnvifMediaProfile profile, @NotNull String uri) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        System.out.println("URL " + uri); //Printing RTSP URL
                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Pass the hostname, username and password you got from OnvifDiscovery  to the mediaURlFinder( ) method, and it will gie you the RTSP link and you can get some other details like manufacturer, serial number etc..
I want mention that in my case I use my mobile phone as IP camera (using IP Webcam application ) and this code gave RTSP link.

Answer (score 1):

This code is using the Onvif protocol. But IP webcam android app may not be a Onvif device, so this device can not communicate with your the code.
This like:
You are British, I am Vietnamese. You say "What you name?", I don't understand. I need learn English. Like your IP webcam need setup Onvif protocol.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering @james Z, But the things is I can get the RTSP links of IP cameras. Still I can't get the port number of ip cameras.. If you have any solutions for this kindly help me with this. And once again thank you very much

Comment: how do you get RTSP link of IP cameras? Can you show me your code or your way to do that

Comment: @Vittel Solutions, hi, when I post this issue, I am doing this task with spring boot, now I complete this task with 'onvif-nvt' and node-onvif NPMs. and I can't paste my whole code here in comment section due to character limitation. Thank you once again.